# Procedure working when called exec sp but fails when executed from c# using process.exit() command

Tags: python, c#, sql, powershell, process

I am able to successfully execute a dbo.sp_addlinkedserver from SSMS but its failing with below error when executed from c# using process.WaitForExit() command line arguments.

Error : (15002, b"The procedure 'sys.sp_dropserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

---------------- Procedure -----------------

```
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'test', @droplogins='test'
  GO


   /****** Object:  LinkedServer [ASLODS]    Script Date: 1/28/2021 3:40:13 AM ******/
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'test', @srvproduct=N'test', 
  @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'test'
    /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'test', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
@optvalue=N'true'
GO
GO
```

c# code to call procedure file for execution

```
      using (Process process = new Process())
        {process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            if(workingDir != null)
            {
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
            }               
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            .......................
             .........................
             ...........................
            Task<bool> waitForExit = WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);
            result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;  //Here it fails. 

I want to execute addLinkedServer procedure from C#.
```

Comment: why are you ding like this? any specific reason? Otherwise, you can read the SQL file and run the query using SqlConnection

Comment: we are executing bulk files from c# thats why using process argument with filepath

Comment: then you can create a batch file (define how to run the scripts in this )and run the batch file like this

Comment: for some reason we are using this approach and this code is already in production so cant change it